# IE8 post file targeting iframe, arrives on server as null

Tags: iframe, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

I have a form with just an `input:file` in it and the form targets a named `iframe`. when the user selects a file it automatically posts the form to the server. This works in IE10/firefox/chrome, but in IE8 the File parameter on my controller method is null when IE8 posts the form. Has anyone else encountered this and know of any solutions, why isn't IE8 actually posting the file data?

ClientSide:

```
function createFileUploadForm()
{
    var frameName = 'fileUploadFormFrame';
    var fileValue;
    var fileUploadCallback = function()
    {
        //do stuff when the server responds after receiving the file
    };
    var fileInputChangedCallback = function(event)
    {
        if(fileInput.value != fileValue)
        {
            fileValue = fileInput.value;
            form.submit();
        }
    };

    var iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    iFrame.name = frameName
    document.body.appendChild(iFrame);

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = 'a/valid/url';
    form.method = 'post';
    form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
    form.target = frameName;

    var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
    fileInput.type = 'file';
    fileInput.name = 'File';
    fileInput.accept = '.spc';
    fileValue = fileInput.value;

    //all browsers except IE8
    //add event listener to fileInput onChange event -> fileInputChangedCallback

    //IE8 fix
    //add event listener to fileInput onFocus event -> fileInputChangedCallback

    form.appendChild(fileInput);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

ServerSide:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase File)
{
    //do stuff with File, but in IE8 File parameter is null
}
```

Comment: Funny timing, as I was just now rebuilding a file manager interface that uses iframe targeting and supports IE8. Can you post a little bit of the code you're using?  BTW, in my code I have a 250ms pause before removing the iframe from the DOM after the upload completes.

Comment: is it giving any error in console? i hope its not a security issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding the client-side code. That's what I was looking for.  I include encoding like that at all time, just so I *know* how it's sent.  BTW, I see a +200 bounty, yet you've submitted your own answer and marked it as the accepted solution.  Is the bounty still active?

Comment: lol no, the bounty was to try and speed up getting an answer, but a colleague at work figured out the issue, so it should really go to him :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem was that IE8 requires an additional `encoding` property on the form to be set:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'a/valid/url';
form.method = 'post';
form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
form.encoding = 'multipart/form-data';  //this additional line fixes the IE8 problem I was having
form.target = frameName;
```