# Iframe file uploading is not working in IE 8 browser

Tags: php, internet-explorer, iframe, file-upload

This is my html

```
   <form id="theuploadform">
   <input id="upload" type="file" name="upload" style="display:none;" />
   <input type="submit" name="" id="fileuploadcsv" value="Upload"> 

    </form>
```

This is my JavaScript file

```
    $("#fileuploadcsv").click(function () {
      
      // e.preventDefault();
      
      // for uploading click
      var uploadValue = '';
      uploadValue     = $("#upload").val();
      if(!uploadValue){

        $('#selectfileerror').removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }else{
         $('#selectfileerror').addClass("hide");
      }

      // Find extension of selected file.
      var ext = ''; 
      ext     = uploadValue.split('.').pop();
      ext     = ext.toLowerCase();

      if(ext != 'csv'){

        $('#fileformaterror').removeClass("hide");
        return false;
      }else{
        $('#fileformaterror').addClass("hide");
      }


      var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none"></iframe>');

      $("#frameappend").append(iframe);

      var form = $('#theuploadform');
      form.attr("action", "/elearning/import_courses");
      form.attr("method", "post");
      form.attr("file", $('#upload').val());
      // form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
      form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
      form.attr("target", "postiframe");
      
      form.submit();

      $("#postiframe").load(function () {

        alert("postframe load");

        iframeContents = this.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        alert(iframeContents);
      });
      return false;
  });

});
```

This working fine in other browsers. There is no error showing and alert null in IE.

What can I do to investigate this?

Comment: So you still want to support IE8? You must have very good reasons for that. See; https://www.w3schools.com/Browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Also checked IE 9+, not working

Comment: Hmmm, IE8 and IE9 together could have a market share as high as 2%, it's starting to become relevant, but it very much depends on who will visit your site.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789983/ie8-post-file-targeting-iframe-arrives-on-server-as-null ?

Comment: yes. not worked. thanks